# When the rate of acceleration changes it's sign how does the velocity change?

Tags: acceleration, velocity, differentiation

When the rate of acceleration changes its sign how does the velocity change?  When another derivative of distance with respect to time is increased how does it affect factors like displacement and velocity?

Comment: It is called "jerk". This will affect concavity of v against t graph. Beyond that I think there be no characteristic changes and becomes a maths question.

Comment: derivative of distance with respect to time Is call velocity?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the “rate of acceleration” is a little confusing. Are you saying the the acceleration changes its sign, or that the rate of change of the acceleration changes its sign?  Assuming the former, acceleration is a vector quantity.  It has a magnitude (which is always positive) and a direction. Only the components of a vector can be negative, and that depends your choice of a coordinate system. If the x component of acceleration goes from + to - , then the x component of the rate of change of velocity will go from + to - . (A velocity in the negative x direction will go from decreasing to increasing.)

Comment: I am talking about the change of sign of acceleration da/dt.